# How to write the constant in my function?

Tags: php, function, constants

```
function insert_data($array){
    $dbh=new PDO('sqlite:C:\test.sqlite');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (symbol,price) VALUES (?,?)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($array);
    $dbh=null;
}
```

I want to define `C:\test.sqlite`  as a constant.

```
define('db_name','C:\test.sqlite');
```

But i can't use the constant in my function insert_data.

```
function insert_data($array){
    $dbh=new PDO("sqlite:db_name");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (symbol,price) VALUES (?,?)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($array);
    $dbh=null;
}
```

An error occur :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in....
```

I don't want to write the function as the format :

```
 function insert_data($array,$db){
    $dbh=new PDO("sqlite:{$db}");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (symbol,price) VALUES (?,?)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($array);
    $dbh=null;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Why not use `global`?

Comment: Use a global variable `$db_name = 'C:\test.sqlite'` outside your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define variable - `$db = 'C:\test.sqlite';`

And make it `global`.

```
function insert_data($array){
    global $db;
    $dbh=new PDO("sqlite:{$db}");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (symbol,price) VALUES (?,?)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute($array);
    $dbh=null;
}
```

[Read it here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)